# Multiple ballons in google earth api

Tags: google-earth-plugin

**how to show multiple balloons at same time in Google earth API? Is any trick can be made like increasing place mark icon size? **

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Google Earth both the desktop program and the browser plug-in only allow having one 'balloon' showing at any one time.

Comment: thank you for replying, can we show large marker image which we can design to look like balloons, I tried this but large image show only in maps mode, when i switch to earth mode, no marker is shown.

Comment: You could try using a different icon for each placemark, using maybe an image which has your desired look/info. This requires creating a unique <Style> in the KML file and assigning the image to the <icon>